# how to clear an label value in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have  an  label "test"  comimg  from  .cs  [c#  code] text="data saved  successfully" .   but once  I  click the  save    button  i  need  to  **clear its  text** 
right now I have  3  required  field  validators. with message     [cannot be  blank, cannot be  blank,cannot be  blank,]   as user  as  clicked the save  button   I need to  clear the  text  of the  label. But  need  to  show the  required fields  validator message

any idea  how  to  solve it

thank you

Answer (score 1):

make a javascript function like:

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
function clearText(cntId) {
  var cnt = document.getElementById(cntId);
  cnt.value ="";
  return false;
}
</script>

then on your submit button attach a client side event

<asp:Button id='btnSubmit' Text='Submit' onClientClick='clearText("<%this.lblLable.ClientId%>");' .... />
```

Comment: In this case will the Page Validation takes place, say there are three text boxes which are to be validated on the click of Save Button? Thanks.

Comment: Yes... The page validation will work as usual. The validations are invoked from with in the Click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side use a script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clearLabelValue(){
     var labelObj = document.getElementById("<%= myLabel.ClientID %>");
     labelObj.value = "";
  }
</script>

<asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server" Text="Some text"/>
<asp:Button id="myButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="clearLabelValue();return false;"/>
```

Didn't test it in detail, but should work.

It is not really clear what you want to achieve, although I have the feeling there may be a "better" (more standard compliant) way of achieving what you want. Maybe you could describe more clearly what you want, so we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations when a particular button has validation attached to it and also we need to fire some javascript what is done is to define a javascript function which is called on click of save button.

What this javascript function does:

This function will take your label and will set its value as blank so that the text is cleared.

Now in order to validate the page which happens internally (in case the javascript function is not written on the save button click) we need to explicitly call what asp.net call for client side validation.

There is a function page_ClientValidate which needs to be  called from this javascript function so that validation is still done and we also do some other processing like clearing the label in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--for cleaning to label ; -->

document.getElementById("MyLabel").innerHTML = "";


<!--and label is like;-->

<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: This is ASP.Net, therefore the ID "MyLabel" will probably not be the ID of the genrated control. The ID should be the `ClientID` of the control MyLabel.

Comment: it's working on my project. My Label is in the update panel, maybe it's the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this using below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clearLabelValue(){
      document.getElementById("<%= myLabel.ClientID %>").innerText=""

  }
</script>
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
<asp:Button id="myButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="clearLabelValue();"/>
```