# Clear a label by button in a form with validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, client-side-validation, client-side-scripting

Recreated my problem in a very simple webform with `TextBox1`, `Button1` and `Label1`. I use "validation" (client side) on `TextBox1` so if it's empty a message is shown.

In code behind (server side) - `Label1` is set.

I use javascript to clear `Label1`, but it doesn't work.

```html
<head runat="server"><title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function ClearLabel() { $('#Label1').val(""); }
     </script>
</head>
<body><form id="form1" runat="server">
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_1" runat="server"
              ErrorMessage="pls enter value" Text="*" ControlToValidate="TextBox1">
           </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" 
           OnClientClick="ClearLabel()" 
           OnClick="Button1_Click" />
       <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="List" />
</form></body></html>
```

Code behind :

```cs
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {if (Page.IsValid)
        {Label1.Text = ("value is : " + TextBox1.Text);}}
```

The javascript to clear `Label1` is not fired or not working.
Where am I going wrong...?

Comment: not `$('#Label1').val("");`. just try this `$('#Label1').text("")`

Comment: Try looking at the generated HTML on the web page and you'll notice that the label control has a different name to what you pt in originally. You need to register your JavaScript segment first so that it can access the ASP.NET rendered content. [Have a read of this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx).

Comment: I didn't test that code. check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692856/how-to-clear-an-label-value-in-javascript.

Comment: @gradi. if these codes doesn't work, let me know

Comment: Than you all. No - it does not work yet. Tried all suggestions here.  Is there a way to check if the javascript is fired at all, something like response.write? (javascript is new to me)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code from `$('#Label1').val("");` to `$('#Label1').text("")`. 
[Set Label Text with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903822/set-label-text-with-jquery).

EDIT:

Or , you can use this `document.getElementById("#Label1").innerHTML='';` instead of `$('#Label1').text("")`(jquery code)

Comment: This will not necessarily work as expected. In fact, I would suspect that it will fail due to ASP.NET rendering controls with different names. See my comment in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it -
In the code behind I added an "else" statement:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        { 
            Label1.Text = ("value is : " + TextBox1.Text); 
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

In my html I completely removed the javascript, but I still nedded the OnClientClick stuff with a **dummy** function, like this :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_1" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="pls enter value" Text="*" ControlToValidate="TextBox1">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save"
        OnClientClick="blablabla"
        OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="List" />
</form>
</body>
```

Notice the name of the non existing dummy function it calls, without which it wouldn't work :

```
    OnClientClick="blablabla"
```

It works fine and as expected, though I have no clue how it does it. So I found some tutorials and will spend the next couple of days getting to know javascrit.
Thank you all!
Gadi